# On scroll animate to next div on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have been trying to search for different things, but I couldnt find the suiting solution for my problem.

I need to scroll to the next div, when you swipe up on the iPad, so the div's top snaps to the ipads top. I think this would be simply `on .scroll` in combination with `.scrollTop()`, right? So now when you scroll, it should detect either you scroll down or up, and when you do so, jump to the next or previous div.

Has anyone a ressource, where I can find a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the exact same thing a while ago for my **[Personal Website](http://www.a-jafari.com)**. (if you check it with a tablet or a smart phone you can see it in action)

what I used was:

1. **[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/):** to detect touch moves and unbind the scroll
2. **[Touch Swipe Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin):** to detect the direction of swipe
3. And the rest is simple jQuery animation using `scrollTop()` and `offset()`

Comment: Looks awesome! I will try this and come back here to tell if it works, for now I will check it as answered, as your page on tablet is the way I want it to work